# проблемы роутинга react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

Возникла проблема с react приложением. Есть бэк на express и фронт на React с использованием react router.
При разработке, express был на порту 3001, а фронт на 3000 и связывался при помощи proxy.
Суть проблемы заключается в том, что после запуска "npm run build" и добавления в бэк строк

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build/index.html'))
});
```

приложение работает нормально только если начинать работать с ним с главной страницы, то бишь 'localhost:3001/'. Но если в адресной строке указать сразу 'localhost:3001/books', то это воспринимается как запрос к серверу и выдается чистый json без react приложения.
Не понимаю что можно с этим сделать-не кидать же по каждой ссылке index.js.

UPD: пример запроса к "localhost:3001/books"

```
router.get('/', async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const allBooks = await BookPool.query('SELECT * FROM "Books" ORDER BY id');    
        res.status(200).json(allBooks.rows);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: *не кидать же по каждой ссылке index.js.* - именно это и надо сделать :) Конечно, кроме ссылки, ведущий на АПИ.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko не могли бы вы тогда пожалуйста пояснить как это сделать? вот есть у меня, например, "localhost:3001/books" код запроса добавил в основной вопрос.

И что мне надо сделать, чтоб меня отправило не на homepage, а именно на books, да еще чтоб запрос из бд не потерять

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter -- localhost:3001/#books

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov спасибо,частично это проблему решило. Но проблема все еще остается. по localhost:3001/books все еще торчит сырой json. может можно его как нибудь спрятать? или редиректнуть как нибудь с  localhost:3001/books на  localhost:3001/#/books

Comment: Вам надо по всем запросам(кроме запросов к АПИ) отдавать `index`, потом роутинг возьмет на себя react.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko в том то и дело, что очевидный адрес это "domain-name.com/books", а не  "domain-name.com/#/books". Поэтому если человек захочет зайти сразу на эту страницу, то попадет в запрос к АПИ. можно ли это как то исправить?

Comment: Можно! По запросу "domain-name.com/books" отдавать index. А для апи сделать поддомен - api.domain-name.com. Ну или каким-то способом узнавать, что запрос на вьюху или запрос к апи идет. Если у вас "domain-name.com/books" и запрос к АПИ и для показа страницы - тогда плохо, надо переделывать.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko премного благодарен! Добавил субдомен (спасибо либе 'express-subdomain') и сейчас вынесу туда апишку